# Расширение не ищет элементы(изолирование)

Tags: javascript

Ребят, этот код вставляется в расширение и должен искать кнопку с текстом "Найти друзей". Если я вставляю этот код в расширение, то у меня сразу в console.log возникает уведомление, что "Кнопка не найдена", НО если вставлять этот код в vk.com/friends в консоли браузера, то нужная кнопка с текстом показывается, но конкретно расширение не выводит его. Может быть, проблема на стороне сайта? Он как-то изолирует? Или проблема в manifest.json?(Его я прикреплю ниже)

```js
function findTicketButton() {
  const buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
  for (let button of buttons) {
    if (button.textContent.trim() === 'Найти друзей') {
      return button;
    }
  }
  return null;
}

const ticketButton = findTicketButton();

// Вывод найденной кнопки в консоль
if (ticketButton) {
  console.log('Кнопка найдена:', ticketButton);

  ticketButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const selectedOption = document.getElementById(selectId).value;
    if (selectedOption) {
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
        type: 'buttonClicked',
        status: selectedOption,
      });
    }
  });
} else {
  console.log('Кнопка не найдена');
}
```

manifest.json

```js
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Click Counter",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Расширение для подсчета кликов на кнопке",
  "permissions": ["tabs", "https://*/*", "http://*/*"],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["js/content_script.js"]
    }
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["js/background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: где этот код расположен? Когда ты его вызываешь?

Comment: Скорее всего вы ищите кнопку либо в `popup.html`'e (попытайтесь для примера найти элемент который существует у вас в этом файле), либо у вас скрипт в контент скриптах. Чтобы получить доступ к DOM структуре текущей страницы нужно обращаться к элементам в background скриптах.

Comment: @ΝNL993 т.е., если расширению необходимо работать в фоновом режиме, например, что-то брать с сайта автоматически, пока оно работает и сайт активен, то код нужно добавлять в background.js? Кнопку я ищу на любом сайте с определенным текстом.

Comment: @Ярослав если вы из кнопки получаете конкретную информацию, допустим: строку, число или объект (объект нужно будет сконвертировать в строку с помощью `JSON.stringify`), тогда можно через хранилище передавать из background.js прямиком в скрипт который расположен в popup'е. Про хранилище можно почитать [на MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage).